# Set Tabitem Header to Menuitem Header in Wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, workspace

I am developing a desktop software using WPF and I would like to use tab control to view different forms. Am also studying MVVM. I have managed to create a new tab control every time a menu is clicked. How can I set the tabitem header to be the same as the menuitem clicked header. Here is the code of what I have done so far!

Here is the view:

```
 <MenuItem Header="_File">
     <MenuItem Command="{Binding NewWorkspaceCommand}" Header="_New Tab" InputGestureText="Ctrl + N" />
     <MenuItem Command="{Binding CloseWorkspaceCommand}" Header="_Close Tab" InputGestureText="Ctrl + F4" />
     <MenuItem Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" Header="E_xit" InputGestureText="Ctrl + X" />
 </MenuItem>



<TabControl x:Name="tbMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" Opacity=" 0.90"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window }}}">
    <TabControl.Background >
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/images/background.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</TabControl.Background>

<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Content="X" Margin="4,0,0,0" FontFamily="Courier New" Width="17" Height="17" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl >
```

View Model

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{ 

    #region Constructor

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        invokemenuClick;
        Workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
        Workspaces.CollectionChanged += Workspaces_CollectionChanged;

    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Handlers

    void Workspaces_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.NewItems)
                workspace.RequestClose += this.OnWorkspaceRequestClose;

        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.OldItems)
                workspace.RequestClose -= this.OnWorkspaceRequestClose;
    }

    private void OnWorkspaceRequestClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloseWorkspace();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    private DelegateCommand _exitCommand;
    public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
        get { return _exitCommand ?? (_exitCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Application.Current.Shutdown())); }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _newWorkspaceCommand;
    public ICommand NewWorkspaceCommand
    {
        get { return _newWorkspaceCommand ?? (_newWorkspaceCommand = new DelegateCommand(NewWorkspace)); }
    }

    private void NewWorkspace()
    {
        frmCustomer oCustomer = new frmCustomer();

        var workspace = new WorkspaceViewModel { Header = "New Tab" } ;

        Workspaces.Add(workspace); 
        /// = oCustomer.Content; 
        SelectedIndex = Workspaces.IndexOf(workspace);

    }

    private DelegateCommand _closeWorkspaceCommand;
    public ICommand CloseWorkspaceCommand
    {
        get { return _closeWorkspaceCommand ?? (_closeWorkspaceCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseWorkspace, () => Workspaces.Count > 0)); }
    }

    private void CloseWorkspace()
    {
        Workspaces.RemoveAt(SelectedIndex);
        SelectedIndex = 0;
    }


    #endregion
```

I would like to set the calling menu header where it says `var workspace = new WorkspaceViewModel { Header = "New Tab" } ;` where "New Tab" is the name of the calling menuItem.

I hope I have explained myself.

Thanx in advance for your help!
`

Comment: Does your `RelayCommand` accept a `CommandParameter`? If so, you could pass in the `MenuItem` that was clicked to your command.

Comment: I am interested in the RelayCommand Parameter as mentioned by Mike. How do I impliment that?